# Атрибут для uppercased()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, мобильная-разработка

Пишу набор атрибутов, что бы узнать высоту текста хранящегося в UILabel. Для строки с обычным текстом это сделать удалось. Но для заголовка рассчитать никак не получается.
Проблема в том, что заголовок выводится БОЛЬШИМИ буквами а длинна рассчитывается для обычной строки. Вот код:

```
        if let feed = self.datasource?.item(indexPath) as? Feed{
        let approximateWidthOfTitlePost = view.frame.width - 15 - 15
        let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfTitlePost, height: 1000)
        let attributeShortContent = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]

        let attributeTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]


        let estimatedFrameContent = NSString(string: feed.shortContentPost).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeShortContent, context: nil)

        let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: feed.titlePost).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)


        let sized: CGFloat = 15 + 30 + 10 + 260 + 10 + estimatedFrameTitle.height + 10 + 15 + 10 + estimatedFrameContent.height + 20 + 20 + 15
        print(sized)


        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 15 + 30 + 10 + 260 + 10 + estimatedFrameTitle.height + 10 + 15 + 10 + estimatedFrameContent.height + 20 + 20 + 15)
    }
```

Неправильное значение получается в `estimatedFrameTitle.height`
Для вывода заглавных букв используется `.uppercased()`

Comment: А почему высота UILabel не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: feed.titlePost).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)
```

замени на

```
let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: feed.titlePost.uppercased()).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)
```